# How does Spark handle memory in local mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to get a grasp about how Spark (2.1.1) handles memory in local mode.

As far as I understand, when I launch spark-shell with `--driver-memory 3g`:

- 300MB is reserved
- 60% (default of `spark.memory.fraction`) is used
  for the rest, shared between execution and storage - 1.7GB

Presumably some of this is also shared with spark-shell and the Spark UI.

Looking at running processes, I see the java.exe process for spark-shell using about 1GB of RAM after a fresh launch.

If I then read in a 900MB CSV file using:

`val data: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", value = true).csv("data.csv")`

And then repeatedly call `data.count`, I can see the java.exe process creep up each time, until it caps out at about 2GB of RAM.

A few questions:

1. Why does it cap at 2GB? Is that number the 1.7GB usable + 300MB reserved?
2. What is actually in that memory, since I'm not caching anything?
3. When it hits that 2GB cap, what's happening on subsequent calls to `data.count`? It clearly ate more memory on previous calls, so why does it not need more once it hits that cap?